# Plugin to use gitolite's ACLs for CGIT/Apache httpd?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, gitolite, cgit

We use gitolite's ACL mechanism to control who has access to different repositories.  We also use CGIT with Apache httpd to allow browsing of readable repositories.

We'd like to also use the gitolite ACLs in the Apache httpd access control system.

Is there an Apache httpd authn/authz module that provides this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated CGit and gitolite a while ago with this cgi Perl script, calling gitolite: [`cgit/cgit.pl.tpl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/cgit/cgit.pl.tpl).
(don't mind the `@H@`, those are template placeholder that are supposed to be valued later in order to produce the actual Perl script)

The idea is to benefit from the authentication done by Apache:

```perl
my $remote_user=$ENV{"REMOTE_USER"};
```

And to use that user when calling Gitolite to check if the access to a repo can be granted, calling the actual `cgit.cgi` C procedure if the access is granted:

```perl
use Gitolite::Rc;
use Gitolite::Common;
use Gitolite::Conf::Load;

(my $repo)=($path_info =~ /\/([^\/]+)/);
  my $perm = "R";
  if ($repo ne "") {
  my $aperm = access( $repo, $user, 'R', 'any' );
  # my ($aperm, $creator) = &repo_rights($repo);
    $perm=$aperm;
  }
  if ($perm !~ /DENIED/) {
    system("@H@/cgit/cgit.cgi");
  }
  else {
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "<html>\n";
    print "<body>\n";
    print " <h1>HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied</h1>\n";
    print " You don't have access to repo <b>$repo</b> as <b>$user</b>\n";
    print "</body>\n";
    print "</html>\n";
  }
```